# How to comment #if, #else, #endif preprocessor construct?

Tags: c++, c, coding-style, comments

Imagine a C preprocessor block:

```
#if defined( NAME )
...
#else  // comment-else
...
#endif  // comment-endif
```

Such blocks can be quite large and confusing.

To clarify intent and behaviour, how would you write *comment-else* and *comment-endif* as an expression of NAME ?

Note: I should add that I'm especially interested the more complicated cases with combined expressions and nesting.

Comment: Obviously in C it has to be /* comment */

Comment: obviously you haven't been following ISO as recently as 1999 ;-p

Comment: The obvious way is to not make the sections large and confusing. :-). Move the code to separate functions and include the ones you need for each configuration.

Answer (score 14):

```
#if defined(NAME)
#else // defined(NAME)
#endif // defined(NAME)
```

This is, if used throughout your source, completely unambiguous.

Comment: Btw, i find using // in a preprocessor directive deeply disturbing, in this case it's completely correct, but still ;-)

Comment: Completely agree. I avoid this unless it gets to a point where I really can't read the code without them. I tend to also indent these though.

Comment: I mean, you should use /* */ not // :)

Comment: @stefan Why is it "deeply disturbing", and why should one use `/* */` rather than `//`? (I see the smileys, but if this is a joke I don't get it.)

Comment: // isn't valid in C89/90, they are in C99/c++

Comment: I use `/* */` as a legacy from when I had to use a compiler that refused to recognise `//` comments only in preprocessor directives - it accepted them in the rest of the code. It is going back a few years but it's a habit that I haven't got rid of.

Comment: My point was that if you use a preprocessor directive as a macro you will end up injecting a comment in your code, you prefer having a c-style then.

Comment: @JimBalter It's "deeply disturbing" because of the potential it has for going wrong when used with preprocessor macros.  If you have `//` in a macro definition to document what the macro does, then on lines where the macro is used, everything to the right of the macro will be commented out, whether you wanted it to be or not.  Therefore, people prefer to see `/* */` in macros, and by extension, anywhere they see the preprocessor in use.  It's not problematic to use `//` for preprocessor if blocks, but people may be wary of it on general principle, due to the aforementioned macro issue.

Comment: Ridiculous, erroneous comments on a 5 year old post. Stefan said, years ago, why he found // "deeply disturbing" but his comment was incoherent and nonsensical. You cannot "inject comments" into code. And this answer had nothing to do with // in a macro definition. Of course // ... \ will include the next line as part of the comment, but that's true everywhere, not just in macros. "and by extension, anywhere they see the preprocessor in use" -- no doubt there are *some* people who generalize foolishly, but doing so isn't necessary or wise. P.S. Comments in macro text are never necessary.

Comment: but what about `#ifndef CONDITION` followed by `#endif // CONDITION`?  :/

Answer (score 7):

erm..

```
#if defined( NAME )
...
#else  // NAME
...
#endif  // NAME
```

can't get more obvious than that...

Comment: What about `!defined(NAME)` or `defined(NAME) && !defined(NAME2)`?

Comment: I should state more clearly that it's especially about the complicated cases. I'm interested to see if some agreement on a style for this exists.

Answer (score 2):

```
#if defined(NAME)
    ...
#else
    // !defined(NAME)
    ...
#endif // defined(NAME)
```

Because I don't want `#else // condition` to look even remotely like `#elif condition`. I know, syntax colouring solves that (at least it does if it's smarter about C preprocessor syntax than SO's syntax colourer), and of course I do use syntax colouring. Still.

Answer (score 2):

If you refactor the "large and complicated" code to separate functions, you can easily see the whole section at once.

```
#if defined NAME
    do_something_for_name();
#else
    do_something_without_name();
#endif
```

Doesn't really need any special comment-conventions, does it?

Answer (score 1):

```
#if defined( NAME )
...
#else  /* Else part of NAME */
...
#endif  /* End of NAME */
```

This is how I do it.

While reading/browsing the code (assuming you are using VIM editor in linux) us the **%** `(Shift + 5)` to jump from `#if` to `#else` and `#endif` easily.

Comment: I'd like to be able to read and comprehend it without tools, e.g. from paper.